# Properties of the generalized centering matrix

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance-matrix, matrix, matrix-decomposition

Let $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}\in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ be the generalized centering matrix given by:

$L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}} = \boldsymbol{\Delta} - \frac{1}{\text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Delta})} \boldsymbol{\Delta} \boldsymbol{1}_M  \boldsymbol{1}_M^\top \boldsymbol{\Delta} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$, where $\boldsymbol{\Delta} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ is a diagonal matrix of strictly positive entries and $\boldsymbol{1}_M = [1, \ldots, 1]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$.

For $\boldsymbol{\Delta}  = I_{M}$, we recover the classical centering matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix).

I have four questions:

1. Can we show that $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}$ is semi-positive definite?
2. Can we get its eigenvectors and eigenvalues?
3. Any hope to get a simple expression for the precision matrix $(\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{L}_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}\boldsymbol{X}^\top)^{-1}$?
4. How do we show that $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}$ removes a weighted average of the samples?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You asked too many questions in one post.  One for each post is more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting on this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some hint to the first question, the remaining three are tractable, but require more context and answers to them are probably more verbose.  As I commented, it is better to ask them in separate posts and show some of your own work.

You can write $\Delta$ more explicitly as $\Delta = \operatorname{diag}(a_1, \ldots, a_M)$ with $a_i > 0, i = 1, \ldots, M$. Denote the trace of $\Delta$ by $T = a_1 + \cdots + a_M$.  It can be shown that $L_\Delta = \Delta^{1/2}C\Delta^{1/2}$, where
\begin{align}
C = I_{(M)} - \frac{1}{T}vv', \quad v = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{a_1} \\
\sqrt{a_2} \\
\vdots \\
\sqrt{a_M}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Therefore to show $L_\Delta$ is PSD, it suffices to show $C$ is PSD.  But $C$ is symmetric and idempotent, hence PSD.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This really helps me to answer to questions 1,2, and 4. I will follow-up in a new post with more context for question 3.

Comment: So $C$ is an orthogonal projector. From your decomposition, $L_\Delta$ applies a diagonal scaling, removes the weighted mean, and scales again. I will follow-up in a new post with more context for question 3.

Comment: @Mathieu Yes.  By the way, if you found any answer is useful, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.